# How to Maximise and minimise Line charts in Flex using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

In my adobe flex interface window there is two graph at a time .Is it possible to add maximizing & minimizing functionality to these graph so that one can view both graph at a time and if required minimize one ,which leads the other graph to occupy the minimized graphs place.and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Use an accordion.... put one chart in one part of accordion and the other in the other.

http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Accordion check this link to see how to use accordion in flex.

Comment: But using an accordian we can't able to view two graph at a time.I am thinking about a method like dash board.http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/devnet/dashboard/main.html....since I am not too much familiar  with as3 its very difficult for me to understand this script.If I get a less complicated method it will be very helpful...Thanks

Comment: http://hasseg.org/stuff/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanelDemo.swf this is the link to collapsible panels.